# LXQt - iBus / X server won't respond to Alt+Shift for switching keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, lubuntu, ibus, lxqt

I'm using LXQt on Lubuntu 22.04, and am having trouble switching keyboard layouts (between Hebrew and English). I can switch them by mouse, using the iBus panel applet, but - neither RAlt+Shift nor LAlt+Shift affect the layout. This, despite the iBus preferences showing "<Alt><Shift>" as the Next Input Layout shortcut key.

This is actually not a new problem: I also had it with Lubuntu 20.04 which I recently upgraded from.

How can I get both, or even just one of the Alt+Shift combinations to work and switch  keyboard layouts?

Note:

- If I add Ctrl+Shift+Y as a layout switcher - that works (although it brings up a popup dialog  rather than just switching).
- If I add Alt+Shift+Y as a lout switcher - that doesn't work.
- Tried to ask this on askubuntu, got no answers, deleted the question.